# Displaying previously stored uri of image

Tags: java, android, image, uri

I am trying to get images from both camera and gallery and do some stuff on them and then store the original image's uri in SharedPreferences. I can choose from both of them and successfully display them, but for gallery images, as long as I didn't clear the memory (close the app from history), I can retrieve them from sharedprefrences and display them in Imageview, but after closing the app from history, the retrieved URIs don't display anymore.

I am storing the URIs this way:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAPTURE_IMAGE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri imageUri = Uri.parse("file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath());
            storeInPreferences(imageUri.toString());

        } else Toast.makeText(this, "Canceled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } 
    else if (requestCode == REQUEST_GALLERY) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (data != null) {
                storeInPreferences(data.getData().toString());
            }
        } else Toast.makeText(this, "Canceled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

and trying to show the retrieved URIs using this code:

```
 Picasso.with(mContext)
           .load(Uri.parse(getStringUriFromPrefs()))
           .resize(500, 500)
           .error(R.drawable.ic_error)
           .into(holder.iv_card);
```

This happens only for gallery images. Those images that I capture them directly from camera shows well.

This is the uri for gallery image: (I have problem with)

```
CONTENT://COM.ANDROID.PROVIDERS.MEDIA.DOCUMENTS/DOCUMENT/IMAGE%3A378071
```

and this is the uri for camera image:

```
FILE:/STORAGE/EMULATED/0/DCIM/CAMERA/20190202_224630_2332127860148701493.JPG
```

Also I have tried it in API level 18 and it worked well.but in APIs level 22 and 26 it doesn't work. I haven't tried in other API levels.

Answer (score 0):

> this is the uri for gallery image

No, it isn't. It might be the `Uri` after conversion to all caps.

> and then store the original image's uri in SharedPreferences

That will not work reliably. Any `Uri` that you get from things like `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` or `ACTION_PICK` [will work temporarily, in whatever activity that you made those requests in](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/08/10/uri-access-lifetime-shorter-than-you-might-think.html). The `Uri` might not be usable anywhere else, including future copies of your app. As a result, saving a `Uri` like those is not likely to work very well.

Either:

- Do not save the `Uri`, but instead make a copy of the image itself
- Use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`, as then you can use `takePersistableUriPermissions()` on `ContentResolver` to be able to use the `Uri` over time; or
- Do not use an `Intent` to choose the image, but instead use [a file picker library](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/35?sort=created) or something similar